# Lorentz invariance of Quantum Electrodynamics

Tags: special-relativity, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge, helicity

In chapter 5 of Weinberg QFT (Vol.$1$), in section 5.9, Weinberg demonstrated through an explicit calculation that there cannot be a massless vector field with helicities $\pm 1$. In fact, Weinberg has shown that if you go through the algebra, you recover canonical quantization in the Coulomb gauge.

My questions are:

1. How does the canonical quantization in the Lorenz gauge fit into this? I understand that in the Lorenz gauge quantization, we have two transverse polarization vectors, one longitudinal and one scalar. How can we repeat the derivation in chapter 5 of Weinberg for the Lorenz gauge?
2. If a Lorentz invariant massless vector field of helicity $\pm 1$ doesn't exist, how do we see that QED is Lorentz invariant?